# Adding dynamically created components to a WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF grid, which needs to have RadioButtons arranged in 3 columns. The radio buttons represent each of a category, which is evaluated by the model. I have also created a property of type UIElementCollection in the ViewModel. Now the challenge is to arrange them in the grid i.e, assigning the row column values to each.

MainWindow xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="WPFApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFApplication"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:WPFApplication.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Width="auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- The problem with this expander is that the rows are not dynamically added.
             Also, all radio buttons are selectable.-->
        <Expander Name="ExpanderProductCategory" Header="Product Categories" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto">
            <Expander.DataContext>
                <ViewModels:ProductCategoriesViewModel/>
            </Expander.DataContext>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCategories}">

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="gridRegions" Margin="5,10,0,0" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid>

                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                    
                    <DataTemplate>                        
                        <RadioButton Content="{Binding Name }" Grid.Row="{Binding RowIndex}" Grid.Column="{Binding ColumnIndex}" Margin="0,0,5,5" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
        </Expander>

        <!-- The problem with this expander is that all radio buttons are selectable-->
        <Expander Name="ExpanderProductCategory2" Header="Product Categories Uniform Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto">
            <Expander.DataContext>
                <ViewModels:ProductCategoriesViewModel/>
            </Expander.DataContext>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCategories}">

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid>

                        </UniformGrid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RadioButton Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,5,5" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
        </Expander>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel code :

```
namespace WPFApplication.ViewModels
{
    class ProductCategoriesViewModel
    {
        private ProductCategory[] _productCategories = { new ProductCategory( "Home Appliances",0,0),
           new ProductCategory( "Personal Care",1,0),
            new ProductCategory("Groceries",2,0),
            new ProductCategory( "Apparels",0,1),
            new ProductCategory("Stationary",1,1),
            new ProductCategory("Toys",2,1),
            new ProductCategory("Kitchenware",0,2) };

        public ProductCategory[] ProductCategories
        {
            get { return _productCategories; }
        }

        private string[] _productCategoriesString = { "Home Appliances",
           "Personal Care",
            "Groceries",
            "Apparels",
            "Stationary",
            "Toys",
            "Kitchenware"};

        public string[] ProductCategoriesString
        {
            get { return _productCategoriesString; }
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest me the right way to handle this case in WPF and MVVM.

Comment: If you're asking about MVVM, you should have an ItemsControl with an ItemContainerStyle where the Grid.Column and Grid.Row properties are bound to view model properties.

Comment: @Clemens the answers that you suggested me, deals with setting grid row column, in the behind code. But my concern is that i have to do it from ViewModel. I might be wrong here, and in that case would like to know how to correctly do it. As far as my understanding of MVVM, the categories are fetched by Model, and the ViewModel has the responsibility to arrange and assign the commands to it.

Comment: Added more duplicates. As said, use an ItemsControl.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, the links look relevant to me. Let me give a check.

Comment: @Clemens The links that you shared didn't help. As mentioned in my question, there are radio buttons, so creating a grid for each row doesn't help. Secondly, i also want to add rows to the grid dynamically. Please refer the updated question.